# Can not read values/nodes from xml using c#

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I'm trying to read values from following xml (which is previously fetched from FTP):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<eventdata xmlns="http://www.demoweb.net/xml/eventdata" >
<site>
<sitelink>demotesting</sitelink>
<user>15101991</user>
<measurement>
 <nodelink>012019120312064500</nodelink>
 <containername>A1</containername>
 <time>2020-04-30T11:25:35</time>
 <value type="n_v_unitvalue">0.04</value>
 <value type="n_v_unitvalue_diff">0.040</value>
</measurement>
<measurement>
 <nodelink>012019120312064501</nodelink>
 <containername>A2</containername>
 <time>2020-04-30T11:25:35</time>
 <value type="n_v_unitvalue">0.0</value>
 <value type="n_v_unitvalue_diff">-0.001</value>
</measurement>
<measurement>
 <nodelink>012019120312064502</nodelink>
 <containername>A3</containername>
 <time>2020-04-30T11:25:34</time>
 <value type="n_v_unitvalue">0.0</value>
 <value type="n_v_unitvalue_diff">0.000</value>
</measurement>
</site>
<createdate>2020-04-30T11:25:35</createdate>
</eventdata>
```

Before I start, file is sucessfully loaded into memory :)

As you can see root node is `eventdata`, and `site` is the node where all data is contained.
So basically I need to loop all `measurement` nodes and get the data.

I also were struggling to get out user node.. here's what I've tried so far:

```
using (StreamReader xml_reader = new StreamReader(xml_response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string xml = xml_reader.ReadToEnd();
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.LoadXml(xml);

    XmlNodeList mainFileContent = xmldoc.SelectNodes("eventdata");
    // XmlNodeList mainFileContent = xmldoc.SelectNodes("eventdata/site");
    XmlElement root = xmldoc.DocumentElement;

    if (mainFileContent != null)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode node in mainFileContent)
        {
            var user = node["user"].InnerText;   
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm missing?

THANKS GUYS

CHEERS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `eventdata` node has own `xmlns` declaration, you should properly handle it using [`XmlNamespaceManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager?view=netcore-3.1) and select the nodes with `x:eventdata/x:site` XPath expression

```cs
var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.LoadXml(xml);

var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", xmldoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);

var mainFileContent = xmldoc.SelectNodes("x:eventdata/x:site", nsmgr);
foreach (XmlNode node in mainFileContent)
{
    var user = node["user"]?.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: and that's only reason why I had to use XmlNamespaceManager.. because root node has own xmlns declaration?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro yes, because your xml namespace is different from default ones, listed in [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.addnamespace?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to read measurement

```
   using (StreamReader xml_reader = new StreamReader(xml_response.GetResponseStream()))
   {
                string xml = xml_reader.ReadToEnd();
                XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmldoc.LoadXml(xml);

                var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.demoweb.net/xml/eventdata");
                XmlNodeList mainFileContent = xmldoc.SelectNodes("ns:eventdata/ns:site",nsmgr);
                XmlElement root = xmldoc.DocumentElement;

                if (mainFileContent != null)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode site in mainFileContent)
                    {
                        var user = site["user"].InnerText;
                        XmlNodeList measurements = site.SelectNodes("ns:measurement", nsmgr);
                        if (measurements != null)
                        {
                            foreach (XmlNode measurement in measurements)
                            {
                                var containername = measurement["containername"].InnerText;
                                var time = measurement["time"].InnerText;
                                XmlNodeList values = measurement.SelectNodes("ns:value", nsmgr);
                                if (values != null)
                                {
                                    foreach (XmlNode value in values)
                                    {
                                        var type = value.Attributes["type"].Value;
                                        var v2 = value.InnerText;
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: how to get `<value type=.." ` below time node?